# Date time in Arabic JavaScrript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a problem in JavaScript function

```js
var tDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar-US", { 
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).format(Date.now()) +
  '\xa0\xa0/ \xa0' +
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar-FR-u-ca-islamic", {
  day: 'numeric', 
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).format(Date.now());

console.log(tDate);
```

the output in Arabic is :
4 أبريل 2020  /  11 شعبان 1441 هـ

in English :
April 5, 2020  /  Shaʻban 12, 1441 AH

what is the problem in Arabic , number 4 moved to left why??

Answer (score 1):

The output of date formatting using the Intl object is not necessarily consistent across implementations. For me, the OP code produces different results in different browsers:

- Safari: ٦ أبريل، ٢٠٢٠  /  ١٣ شعبان، ١٤٤١
- Firefox: ٦ أبريل ٢٠٢٠  /  ١٣ شعبان ١٤٤١ هـ
- Chrome: 6 أبريل 2020  /  13 شعبان 1441 هـ

None of them are exactly the same in format or characters.

If you want to ensure the components are in the order you want, use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts), collect the parts then output them in the order you want. Just ensure the result is unambiguous (e.g. use the month name as you've done).

```js
let partsHeg = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-FR-u-ca-islamic', {
  day: 'numeric', 
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).formatToParts(Date.now());

partsHeg.forEach(part => {
  if (part.type != 'literal') {
    console.log(part.type + ': ' + part.value);
  }
});

let partsGre = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ar-US', {
  day: 'numeric', 
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).formatToParts(Date.now());

partsGre.forEach(part => {
  if (part.type != 'literal') {
    console.log(part.type + ': ' + part.value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding a one (1) statement/code of the RTL Unicode to fix the direction. This happens when the last or first letter in an Arabic text is a Latin char.

```js
let RTL = "\u200F";       // Added ****
var tDate = RTL + new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar-US", {  // Added RTL before
  day: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).format(Date.now()) +
  '\xa0\xa0/ \xa0' +
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat("ar-FR-u-ca-islamic", {
  day: 'numeric', 
  month: 'long',
  year: 'numeric'
}).format(Date.now());

console.log(tDate);                  // You can add RTL here instead console.log(RTL+tDate);
```